# Why does Rust have both call by value and call by reference?

Tags: rust, calling-convention

Some languages, like Haskell, make no distinction between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. The compiler can then approximately choose the most efficient calling convention with a heuristic. One example heuristic would be for the Linux x64 ABI: if the size of parameter is greater than 16 bytes, pass a pointer to the stack otherwise pass the value in registers.

What is the advantage of keeping both notions of pass-by-value and pass-by-reference (non-mutable of course) in Rust and forcing the user to choose?

Could it be the case that pass-by-value is syntactic sugar for pass-by-reference + copy if the value is seen to be modified?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two things:

1. Rust will transform certain pass-by-value calls into pass-by-reference, based on a similar heuristic.
2. Pass-by-value indicates ownership transfer, while pass-by-reference indicates borrowing. These are very different, and totally orthogonal from the asm-level concern you're asking about.

In other words, in Rust, these two forms have different semantics. That doesn't preclude also doing the optimization, though.

Comment: I agree on 2. But this seems like type-checking level, so after type-checking - can the code-generation be identical?

Comment: @ŁukaszLew: Yes, although whether it *does* is another issue entirely :)

Answer (score 0):

[**Edited**: changed exampled to work in release mode]

It isn't syntactic sugar, as one can see by looking at the generated code.

Given these functions:

```rust
fn by_value(v: (u64, u64)) -> u64 {
  v.0 + v.1
}

fn by_ref(v: &(u64, u64)) -> u64 {
  v.0 + v.1
}
```

then if one was syntactic sugar for another, we'd expect them to generate identical assembly code, or at least identical calling conventions. But actually, we find that `by_ref` passes `v` in the `rdi` and `rsi` registers, whereas `by_value` passes a pointer to `v` in the `rdi` register and has to follow that pointer to get the value: ([see details](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=46f628468f8d2db9728f221417ed570f&version=stable&backtrace=0), use release mode):

```
by_value:
  movq  8(%rdi), %rax
  addq  (%rdi), %rax
  retq

by_ref:
  leaq  (%rdi,%rsi), %rax
  retq
```

Comment: You do not seem to be compiling with optimizations. Using [this version of your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6fd877dbbaa0cded95220a00afc1b6e2&version=stable&backtrace=0) (note all the gyrations to prevent the optimizer from removing the function entirely) and *compiling in release mode*, both functions compile down to the assembly `leaq 1(%rdi), %rax;
retq`. Note all the junk about pushing and popping registers has been optimized away.

Comment: You're right, in optimized mode they become the same. I've now changed to a slightly more involved example which shows different behavior.

Comment: With the most recent change, you aren't comparing apples-to-apples. [Checking the size of the values](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=02d1017d548d2d5ea6ee0cb6cf25a511&version=stable&backtrace=0) shows that a tuple of two `u64` is 16 bytes, the reference is 8 bytes. It's entirely possible that the optimizer has decided that 8 bytes is better than 16.

Comment: Not anymore. Both use leaq now