# Why does Rust allow the same method call on both value and its reference?

Tags: rust, reference, method-call

I am still learning Rust and my question is built upon [Why does Rust have both call by value and call by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562262/why-does-rust-have-both-call-by-value-and-call-by-reference) (but a bit different).

With a C/C++ background, I am confused how Rust allows the same method call on both value and its reference. I noticed in *The Rust Programming Language* book that the following code works fine:

```
let s1 = String::from("hello");
let length = s1.len();
let len = calculate_length(&s1);

fn calculate_length(s: &String) -> usize {
    s.len()
}
```

This means that the method call `len()` works on both the `String` value and its reference. I noticed the same thing happens to `Vec<_>` as well. In C/C++ one needs to dereference the pointer to be able to call its method (using operators like `->`); otherwise, there would be a type mismatch. In Rust, does the compiler simply "dereference" the reference for you to call the method or is it because for classes like `String` and `Vec`, multiple methods are implemented under the hood for both the value (e.g., `String`) and the reference (e.g., `&String` and `&str`)?

Comment: *In C/C++ one needs to dereference the pointer to be able to call its method (using operators like `->`); otherwise, there would be a type mismatch.* -- Note this isn't *quite* true; C pointers work this way, but C++ references do not, acting more like aliases, although they often compile to pointers behind the scenes. Rust references have properties of both; they generally act more like C pointers, but code that uses them can look a lot more like C++ code using references because of the syntax.

Comment: Does [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) answer your question, or is there more to it?

Comment: @trentcl That question does answer mine! Thanks for the pointer! Just wondering, are you referring to C++'s polymorphism when you say "*C++ references do not, acting more like aliases, although they often compile to pointers behind the scenes*"? If not, can you elaborate a bit, if you don't mind?

Comment: Nothing to do with polymorphism; C++ references are not pointer-like because you don't have to use the `->` operator with them. For example, consider [these two functions](https://godbolt.org/z/jwwT_g), which compile to the same assembly even though one uses a pointer with `->` and the other uses a reference with `.`